# OutputStream not writing in Java

Tags: java, vb.net, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to write a string value into my arduino port, But it successfully writing but I the machine is not working when i send the command. If I use my arduino software to test the machine it works perfectly. Can I know why I cannot write into my arduino port.

This is my java code:

```
public static void comArduino(){
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
            if (portId.getName().equals("COM6")) {
                try {
                    serialPort = (SerialPort)
                    portId.open("Arduino", 2000);
                } catch (PortInUseException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error1 is "+ e);
                }
                try {
                    outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error2 is "+ e);
                }
                try {
                    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
                        SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                        SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                        SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error3 is "+ e);
                }

                try{
                    Integer number = 1;
                    outputStream.write(number);
                    outputStream.flush();
                    System.out.println(number);

                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Error 3: " + e);
                } 
           }

        }
    }
    serialPort.close();
}
```

This is my vb code:

```
 Private Sub Send_Arduinocmd()
    Dim data1 As String = "1"
    ComArduino.Write(data1)
    MsgBox("sent " + data1 + " to arduino")
End Sub
```

I want to do the same thing in java. Can anyone help me whats the mistake i did.Thank you.

Comment: do you flush or close your `outputStream`?  Do you get an error in Java?

Comment: No I didn't flush my outputstream

Comment: After using flush also it's still the same no respond from the arduino

Comment: Sorry.  I know nothing about this Arduino stuff.  It's going to be hard to help you.  I edited your post to add the `arduino` tag.  Hopefully someone more knowledgeable with that will see it.

Comment: the method which i write is same as in vb? this is because in vb is working just fine just that in java its not working

Comment: Clearly they are not the same.  In VB you are using `ComArduino` and in Java you are using an `outputStream`.  So they are not the same, and I certainly don't know enough to tell you if they are equivalent or not.

Comment: Is your output stream in java really writing to your Ardunio port? You may be writing to system.out in which case you might see the string printed in your ardunio software but it is not going to the port. Did you do something like outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream(); first? Maybe show some more code so we can help you better

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong to me, but one difference is that you write a String in VB but a number in java. Do you get any error message at all?

Comment: No I get the value 1